# port and ip forwarding from local machine to googel.com

Tags: debian, port, iptables, forwarding

I want to see the google main page when I type my virtual machine's ip address in my browser. I want to type in my Windows browser 192.168.132.131:8080 and be redirected to google's main page (173.194.122.198:80).
192.168.132.131 is the ip address of my Debian virtual machine.
How should I open the port 8080 and configure iptables?
I did what this tutorial suggested but didn't get what I wanted.
http://www.debiantutorials.com/port-forwarding-with-iptables/
 please help ...

Answer (score 0):

To see what happens I made tests with a debian-behind-a-linux instead of debian-behind-a-windows because I have no windows. Also (I think) because I'm not in the USA the IP in the example doesn't work for me. I used the IP I get with `ping google.com`

I can just tell that the exemple in your tutorial still works, and if you try by hand on windows `telnet 192.168.132.131 8080` you really connect to google, assuming you made it correctly (what about giving your rules with `iptables-save` ? )

What doesn't work (anymore?) is the HTTP request: HTTP embeds the ip address and sends it to google which doesn't know this URL and will redirect it with a HTTP 301 to google *without* IP in the URL. Alas the HTTP redirection kept port 8080. Since **your debian is not routing this** it can't intercept the flow and the second HTTP request won't be seen by it at all. You get a SYN_SENT on your windows host trying to connect to port 8080 of a google server.

To overcome this you would then (I did) edit your windows' hosts file and add a lot of google names in front of 192.168.132.131 to also have the second request going through the debian VM. This time google sends a HTTP 302 to set the cookie and gives a new URL without port 8080. If you're lucky you'll get a connection reset from the debian box because there's nothing for port 80 there (using a web client like links on the host). But usually google can also see you have a modern browser (Firefox...) and give an HTTPS redirection in the HTTP 302. Now the next connection is to port 443 and encrypted...

The only thing that more or less worked was using links (not Firefox) directly on http://www.google.XX:8080/ with XX being my country code after changing the hosts file (not by using http://192.168.132.131:8080/ ). I could get the search page and even do a search. Using www.google.com (and not being in the US) would redirect to www.google.XX and fail too.

Solution: if it's about HTTP, use an HTTP tool, not a TCP/IP tool: use a proxy (squid, apache...).

If it's for interception, you can use redirection (with iptables) and transparent proxy settings on this proxy but remember if it's not seing traffic because it's not on the router or somewhere uplink, things won't work correctly. Good luck for HTTPS because the web client will complain about man in the middle attacks at best.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comprehensive answer. I figure out what the problem is 3 or 4 hours after I posted this question! I didn't save the rules by iptables-save. And to open port 8080 I installed tomcat7 because apparently it listens to port 8080. I don't know how to open a specific port and this is my main problem ...

Comment: Needing tools to do tests? what about nc (netcat) or even better, socat ?